# Why do I get a 404 error when accessing REST API of my Dockerized Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, gradle, docker-compose

I'm trying to dockerize my services stack consisting of multiple Spring Boot applications.

These services provide REST APIs. They allow to start a job and request the final result.

All of the services offer a REST API which I can access, as expected, when starting the applications with `bootRun` or by executing the built `.jar` files. The response after starting the jobs contains the job's id. This id can be used to request the result of the job.

After creating the Docker images containing the built `.jar`s and starting the containers with `docker compose`, I receive unexpected responses. The response from the containers is an error code `404` instead of either the job id or some other more reasonable error.

The `build.gradle` for one of these services looks something like this:

```gradle
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

group = 'dev.some.path'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.12.0'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

The `Dockerfile` for one of these services looks something like this:

```dockerfile
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
EXPOSE 8080
ARG JAR_FILE=build/libs/service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
ADD ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Changing to a non-alpine version of the base image does not change the result. Dropping the randomizer argument in the entrypoint does not change anything either.

The `docker-compose.yml` for one of these services looks something like this:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  service:
    container_name: service
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8085:8080
```

The output after running `docker compose up` does look promising and very similar to when starting the application either via `bootRun` or by executing the `.jar` file. When trying to access the REST endpoint, the service is responding. The log output is showing that the initialization of the service did complete:

```
service | 2023-05-30T14:20:42.052Z  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
service | 2023-05-30T14:20:42.053Z  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
service | 2023-05-30T14:20:42.054Z  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
```

But the expected behaviour ends there. Instead of logging further hints that the flow continues, the log output stays unchanged and the received response from the request looks something like this:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2023-05-30T14:20:42.097+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "path": "/endpoint"
}
```

Does anyone of you have an idea why this is not working in it's containerized as it is working "regularly"?

Comment: What command are you using to access the service? From where are you running the command?

Comment: @DazWilkin: I tried it with both regular curl and Postman. Neither `POST` nor `GET` requests work. I make the respective REST request to `http://localhost:8085/endpoint`.

Comment: What's the host (Linux, Windows, Mac)?

Comment: It's running on a Linux machine.

Comment: Absent being able to run your containers, I'm at a loss. Can you shell into `services` and try curl'ing the endpoint directly in the container? If not, you could add another service e.g. `radial/busyboxplus:curl` and then try `command: /bin/sh -c "while true; do curl --silent --write-out '%{response_code}\n' http://service:8080/endpoint; sleep 5; done` to see whether another service is able to access it. Or, just run the container standalone (`docker run --interactive --tty --rm --publish=8085:8080/tcp ....`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some more time to look at the issue and I have found the source it.

I started up the stack by calling `docker compose -f firstService/docker-compose.yml -f secondService/docker-compose.yml ... up`.

Apparently, `docker compose` will use the location of the compose file defined in the first position throughout the process. Therefore, while the process was able to locate the proper compose files, it did always copy the `.jar` file from the first service into all containers.

I circumvented this unwanted behaviour by adding the `--project-directory` option to my docker compose command and adapted the `context` field in all `Dockerfile`s. The whole thing works now as expected.